# Calling variable defined in a subroutine outside a subroutine

Tags: perl

I have a subroutine that takes the value of $x and gives that value of $a. I can't access the value of $a outside the subroutine, though, since it tells me $a is undefined. I only learned about subroutines yesterday, so I assume there's something about them I'm missing.

```
sub rout {
  if(@_ == 1) {
    my $a = 3;
  } else {
    my $a = 5;
  }
}

my $x = 1;
rout($x);
print $a;
```

Comment: Hello, please visit following [page](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl_2016/05-perl-functions.html#RnVuY3Rpb25z) related to _functions_ from [Modern Perl](http://modernperlbooks.com/) book.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, don't use `$a` and `$b`. They're a bit special because of their use by `sort`.

---

Secondly, `@_ == 1` checks the number of arguments provided by the caller. This probably not what you wanted to check. You probably wanted to check the value of the first argument: `$_[0] == 1`.

---

The issue is that you are creating a new lexically-scoped variable, assign a value to it, then immediately leave the scope. Your variable is destroyed as soon as you create it! Declare a single variable in the outermost scope where it's needed.

```perl
my $y;

sub rout {
  my ($x) = @_;
  if ($x == 1) {
    $y = 3;
  } else {
    $y = 5;
  }
}

my $x = 1;
rout($x);
print "$y\n";
```

That said, returning a value would make more sense here.

```perl
sub rout {
  my ($x) = @_;
  if ($x == 1) {
    return 3;
  } else {
    return 5;
  }
}

my $x = 1;
my $y = rout($x);
print "$y\n";
```

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning also is that using `my $a` will not trigger `use strict` to report a variable out of scope. A subtle error that may stump new users.